# Calculate Adstock in DAX: how to add value of cell above?

Tags: recursion, powerbi, dax

In Power BI I need to build a so called AdStock measure: This is today's value plus a decayed yesterday's value. Easy and straightforward in Excel like this:

[image]

But how can I do this in DAX?

The solution of the first answers unfortunately is not correct if AdSpend decreases somewhen, the result is not correct from Index 4 on:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Apologies - got careless with my indices. Have corrected my original formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated Column:

```
AdStock :=
VAR AdStockRate = 0.5
VAR ThisIndex = [Index]
RETURN
    [AdSpend]
        + SUMX (
            FILTER ( Table1 , [Index] < ( ThisIndex - [Index] ) ),
            [AdSpend] * AdStockRate ^ [Index]
        )
```

Amend the table name (Table1 here) as required.

Note that I have hard-coded the AdStockRate (0.5) here, though naturally it could be replaced with a dynamic reference.

Or, as a Measure:

```
AdStock :=
VAR AdStockRate = 0.5
VAR ThisIndex =
    MIN ( Table1[Index] )
VAR AdSpend =
    MIN ( Table1[AdSpend] )
RETURN
    AdSpend
        + SUMX (
            FILTER ( ALL ( Table1 ), Table1[Index] < ThisIndex ),
            Table1[AdSpend] * AdStockRate ^ ( ThisIndex - Table1[Index] )
        )
```

Comment: Works perfect with Columns. But I need to use it with "AdSpend" as a measure instead of a column (as I want to be able to multiply "AdSpend" with a What-if-parameter Slicer before). But then I get an error: <pi>A circular dependency was detected: data[TVAdStock], data[Column], data[TVAdStock].</pi>

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work correctly when AdSpend decreases during time, I habe edited this into the question. Is there a fix for this case?

Comment: Apologies - corrected. Will work on a measure version now.

Comment: Great! In the measure version, if Table1[AdSpend] is already a measure, the "MIN" after "VAR AdSpend =" needs to be deleted. I did this and now it works, thanks alot.